# Will ajax in beforeunload reliably execute?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a HTML5 application that needs to send a disconnect ajax request when the user changes/refreshes the page. I am currently using this code:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: api_disconnect,
        data: { identifier: token },
        method: "GET"
    });
});
```

I don't need to process the response, or even ensure that the browser receives a response. My question is, **can I rely on the server receiving the request?**

And if not, **how can I accomplish this?** Currently I have the app send an "I'm alive!" request every 15 seconds (which already feels like too much). I want the server to know the second the user disconnects.

To clarify, I know that if the browser/computer crashes there's nothing I can do about that. That's what the heartbeat is for. I just mean in a normal use case, when the user closes/changes/refreshes the page.

Comment: The answer is easy, **no** you can not !

Comment: As @adeneo said, no. Just think what happens when your client crashes / computer explodes. You might want to have a look at websockets

Comment: Sending a "hearbeat" is the most reliable way to do this, even if the client doesn't crash, some browsers will  close even before the ajax call is made.

Comment: I realize there's no way to know when a crash (for example) occurs, but in my question I state `when the user changes/refreshes the page.`

Comment: If there is no reason for anything to fail (as discussed, client crash - server crash, networking issues, etc...) then yes, this will work.

Comment: since its async it may not fire - you could try making it sync.

Comment: From my experience, it won't work at all. Chrome for instance has a tendency to close the page before the browser has time to send the ajax request, and if you're lucky around half of the requests will go through, so it's completely unreliable. A heartbeat is still the preferred way to check if the user is still there.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot 100% rely on the ajax call getting through.  You can test many browsers and operating systems and determine which ones will usually get the ajax call sent before the page is torn down, but it is not guaranteed to do so by any specification.

The heartbeat like you are using is the most common work-around.  That will also cover you for a loss in network connection or a power-down or computer sleep mode or browser crash which the `beforeunload` handler will not.

Another work-around I've seen discussed is to use a socket.io connection to the server.  Since the socket.io connection has both a small, very efficient heartbeat and the server will see the socket get closed when the page is closed, you kind of get the best of both worlds since you will see an abnormal shut-down via the heartbeat and you will see a normal shut-down immediately via the webSocket connection getting closed.