# Send ajax call on beforeUnload got cancelled by browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, onbeforeunload

I have a web application which requires saving (ajax call) of any unsaved user input data when user navigates away from the site.

I am using "Fetch" to perform the ajax call (saving data) in beforeunload event listener. But browser seemed canceled the ajax call (the preflight OPTIONS call was canceled when I looked at the network panel of Chrome).

jquery has a way to send synchronous ajax call, but that was deprecated. Also, a work around is to popup browser dictated prompt message to let user confirm navigation via beforeUnload event, but that is not preferred by business requirement.

So is there a solution to let the Ajax call get through?

My code sample below. :

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnloadHandler);

beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: api.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Duplicate? [Will ajax in beforeunload reliably execute?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30676368/218196)

Comment: Duplicate: [Save before unload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324365/save-before-unload)

Comment: @RamblinRose Thanks. Experimented according to the post you referred. Adding setTimeout seems a good work around, since save could happen "automatically" for user if he/she chooses to stay on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue , on setting up ajax call as **non-async**, it worked perfectly.

Try adding the below snippet to your ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false })
$.ajaxSetup({ async: false })
```